# Parallel installs of the same app on an Android handset

Tags: java, android, version-control, installation

For my testing of my app I wan't to be able to install a current version and a test version on my handset. In that way I will always be able to test the newest revision in the field, but also be  certain to have the fall-back of the tested code. My app is using a SQLite database which must be accessible to both versions.
I have tried changing the name of the app, but that just changes the displayed name, but still overwrites the previous version.
Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

thats because they work on package basis .so you need to change the package name.atleast for testing

Comment: Thanks - but then I loose access to my data which was in an SQLite DB on the "old" package; any advice on how to maintain data access?

Answer (score 0):

The new Android market management console enables you to keep both versions, but only one can be active.

Increase your version code in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.mypack" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0-SNAPSHOT">
```

and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the package name is the only way to go : Read it there http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html